# How to get Flutter dependencies(yaml file) through some intermediate company place, instead of pub.dev directly

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

Can you please let me know how you can tell flutter-dart to connect to "some company place", from where the data is being drawn, instead of pub.dev directly to get the yaml dependencies?

Comment below from Richard --- I did that --

```
   flutter:
    sdk:flutter
   json_annotation:
    hosted:
      name: json_annotation
      url: "company url that connects with pub dev"
    verison: ^3.0.0
```

....but i keep on getting the error

**pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.**

Comment: Check out: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#hosted-packages and https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages These explain how to use your own pub or in-house git repos.

Comment: I did what it says in the links the variant with hosted, but i keep on getting the error : A dependency may only have one source . Ps : I did check my indentation

Comment: That means json_annotation is also depended on by one of your other dependencies. Use overrides: see https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides